# Getting the video url during WebView onShowCustomView under KitKat

Tags: android, android-webview, chromium, webviewclient

I have been using `onShowCustomView` in order to get the url of the playing video inside a WebView. I was using `HTML5VideoFullScreen$VideoSurfaceView` and getting the "mUri" field but now it seems like the frame has changed to `ContentVideoView$VideoSurfaceView` and I don't see an "mUri" there. Does anyone know where to get that url on kitkat?

Thanks.